# how send id in ajax for laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-6

i want to run my ajax after click on one of the options in select tag. and send id of option to ajax url.

please help me . these are my codes.

```
                @foreach($emails as $mail)

                <option   id="{{$mail->id}}">{{$mail->email}}</option>

                @endforeach

            </select>
```

my ajax

```
    $(document).ready(function () {


        $.ajaxSetup({

            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });

        $('.select option').on('click',function () {
            var id=$('.select option:selected').attr("id");


            $.ajax({
                url:'/mailactive',
                type:'get',
                dataType:'json',
                data:{id:id}

            })
        })
    })
```

Comment: What's the error of this code?

Comment: You did not mention your problem, I mean what error are you getting? If you are not able to find out the problem then inspect the page, goto to network tab then refresh the page. Now select the option from the select box. You will get error information in the network tab for the post-AJAX request.

Answer (score 0):

try to use this:

1. give to your `select` an id, for example `id_select`
2. use `#id_select > option:selected` in your jQuery selector instead of `.select option:selected`

then tell me if you still can't get the id

Answer (score 0):

> **In Your Laravel Blade**

```
<select id="email">

        @foreach($emails as $mail)

        <option id="{{ $mail->id }}"> {{ $mail->email }} </option>

        @endforeach
</select>
```

> **If your Route is POST method**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var id = $('#email').children(":selected").attr("id");

$.post('{{ url('your_POST_route_url') }}', {

                '_token': "{{ csrf_token() }}", id:id,

            }, function (data) {

               console.log(data); // Print your response into your console
    });

 });
```

> **If your Route is GET method**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var id = $('#email').children(":selected").attr("id");

    $.get('{{ url('your_GET_route_url') }}', {

                id:id,

            }, function (data) {

               console.log(data); // Print your response to your console
    });

 });
```

> **You should have return data from your GET or POST method.**